# Axios response showing status code 200 but no response data

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm a newbie to axios. I'm trying to send a post request with an authorization header. The response data is returned in Post man. But I couldn't see any response data in my browser. Please help.

```
   axios.post('http://13.127.3.151:8080/v1/dashboard/getuserdetails', {
      utype: "staff",
      uemail: "abdulwahidnasir@bitsathy.ac.in"
    },
    { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${serviceToken}`,
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
  });
```

[image: Post Man response]
[image: Browser Response]

Comment: What does the network tab show?

Comment: evertything is there in `response.data`.  `DATALIST` is array of len 1 in postman but len 0 in axios request, but I don't think it's a problem with axios.

Comment: FYI.. You **exposed the Bearer token also to the world.** Make sure you change it. This is risky when you have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: The network tab shows empty response in DATALIST

Comment: The bearer token expires every 3 minutes

Comment: Is there any other way where we can test it in our local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, it was with formData. This works fine now.

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("utype", userType);
  formData.append("uemail", email);
  axios.post('http://13.127.3.151:8080/v1/dashboard/getuserdetails', formData,
    { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${serviceToken}`,
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
  });
```